# DOMDocument::load() Timeout

Tags: php, xml, timeout, domdocument

I am using `DOMDocument::load()` to load a XML file from a URL:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("http://url_of_some_xml_file");
```

Is there a way to interrupt or stop loading after defined timeout if the URL took more than X seconds to load?

If this is not possible to be done using `DOMDocument::load()`, is there any other way to set a timeout for loading XML from a URL?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [libxml_set_streams_context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php) to configure the behavior. The [HTTP stream wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) options include `timeout`.

```
$options = [
  'http' => [
    'method' => 'GET',
    'timeout' => '5'
  ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("http://url_of_some_xml_file");
```

Comment: I used this code to set 10 seconds timeout
`$options = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'PHP libxml agent', 'method' => 'GET', 'timeout' => '10'));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
if($doc->load("http://url_of_some_xml_file")){
 //Do something
}
else{
 //timeout exceeded 
}`
it worked fine for me.
Now, let's way that the URL was loaded in less than 10 seconds, how can I know how much it took to load (e.g. maybe it took only 2 secs)?

Comment: Use microtime() before and after the load call.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @thw 's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21497669/15872) of setting the timout option by creating a new steam context, I found that the default stream context uses the `php.ini` setting for `default_socket_timeout` as its timeout.

Changing your `php.ini` like this:

```
; Increase from the default of 60 seconds
default_socket_timeout = 120
```

can be an easy way to increase the timeout without modifying the application code, though this will also affect other stream contexts that use sockets as well.